# Cisco multi switch / multi VLAN monitoring

Tags: cisco, monitoring, port

I have a DMZ and a internal LAN with VLANs that I wish to port monitor by means of a NIDS and three switches, if this is possible.

- Switch 1 (DMZ) 2950 / VLAN 10 & trunk port to Switch 3
- Switch 2 (LAN) 2950 / VLAN 20 & truck port to switch 3
- Switch 3 (MON) 2960 / trunk ports for both VLAN 10/20 & access port
  designated for both VLANs

Now, from what I understand, as long as the trunking between DMZ & LAN switches to the MON switch is correct I should be able to configure SPAN to monitor both those VLANs to a designated port on the MON switch.

Or am I really really off on this?